# How can a java-library using CDI be configured to exclude external beans?

Tags: java, cdi, javabeans

I'm building a CDI-based framework that can be used either by applications or libraries.

To illustrate my question please consider the following:

- Say I have 2 libraries `L1` and `L2`, which depend on my framework
- An application `A` has dependencies on `L1` and `L2` and my framework.
- Each of the above defines beans for internal use only.
- Assume that all of the beans are public and I cannot define a module-info.java file.

How do I avoid that a CDI container initialized by/for `A` will locate the beans which are meant for internal use in `L1` and `L2`? Whilst allowing `L1` and `L2` to use the same container to locate their internal beans?

Comment: I do not think this is possible. Anyway, for what purpose are you trying to achieve this? Would it be so bad if A can find the beans of L1/2? I would argue it may even be a benefit, giving A the opportunity to customize and override the behavior of the libs. I you must absolutely separate the beans, maybe consider other solutions, e.g. OSGi+CDI (I do not know if that would do!!!) or even some kind of custom dependency injection inside the libraries.

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos In my case it would. As the beans in this case are intended as programmed configuration for the libraries. So if application A picks up the beans from these libraries then it will use their configuration, which is not applicable and may cause failures. Your comment did make me think about possibly adding a mechanism which allows for exclusion or inclusion. So thanks for the reply nonetheless!

Comment: Or even consider CDI's alternatives and specializers.

Comment: "A will locate the beans which are meant for internal use in L1 and L2" means: A injects superclasses of certain beans from L1 or L2. But you don't want to have them injected in A as such.
Perhaps you could use library-specific Qualifiers for those local Beans.

Comment: @aschoerk That's actually the approach I was thinking of. I haven't worked it out completely yet but I'm optimistic about this approach.